# Unable to read TXT files from outside a PyPi package

Tags: python, package, pypi

I am having a lot of issues when uploading a PyPi package, because I have a package that reads information from a TXT file in another directory. This is my project structure:

[image: Structure]

I can read the files if I do it using my own package from the PyCharm project, but the problem is when I upload it to `PyPi` and I import is as a pip package.

I read the file in local this way:

> tickers = pd.read_csv('../data/tickers.csv')

But that does not work when I install the package using pip.

I have been trying to configure `setup.py`, but with no succeed, because when I install the package uploaded to PyPi using pip, I get an error like this:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'data/user-agent-list.txt'

This is what I have in my `setup.py` related to those external files contained in the **data/** directory:

[image: setup.py lines]

I also have a **MANIFEST.in** to include the data files:

[image: MANIFEST.in]

I hope the information I provided is enough for you to let me know how can I fix this... To give you extra information, I am following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@joel.barmettler/how-to-upload-your-python-package-to-pypi-65edc5fe9c56) to upload my package to PyPi, but the error has nothing to do with it.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the path 'data/tickers.csv' correct? Or it needs to be starts with  double dot ('../darta/tickers.csv')?

Comment: @AlexKroll yes, the filepath that works when I execute it locally is ../data/tickers.csv. But I don't know if I should use the same for the PyPi package to work :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a (static) file from inside a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028000/how-to-read-a-static-file-from-inside-a-python-package)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+access+package+data

Comment: @alvarobartt - If you found my answer helpful please mark the answer with the green tick on the left.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if the issue is not related to the path you are using here:

```
pd.read_csv('../data/tickers.csv')
```

It refers to the path that is relative to the **base execution path of the script that is using your module**. Try using a non-relative path. You may also want to use the install path as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428059/get-python-install-path-from-running-script).